# Rails - path helper works wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So, I have this route when run `rake routes`

```
faculty_programs GET   /faculties/:faculty_shortcut/programs(.:format)  programs#index
                 POST  /faculties/:faculty_shortcut/programs(.:format)  programs#create
```

Then I expect that `faculty_programs_path` in form_for helper should request for POST

```
/faculties/:faculty_shortcut/programs(.:format)
```

But this:

```
form_for faculty_programs_path(@faculty)
```

Actually generates:

```
<form action="/faculties/phys/programs/new" ... >
```

Although I have:

```
new_faculty_program GET   /faculties/:faculty_shortcut/programs/new(.:format)  programs#new
```

in `rake routes` output.

I can go for monkey patching:

```
form_for "/faculties/#{@faculty.shortcut}/programs"
```

I would like to avoid it, but Rails acts really weird.

Comment: `form_for [@faculty, @program] ` works fine

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
form_for(@faculty, url: faculty_programs_path)
```